# ack-grep to ack in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I was just wondering, i recently installed ack (ack-grep in ubuntu), and i can't figure out how to just type in ack to get ack-grep (for some reason ack is taken up by a kanji translator thing).

Is there a better way than just aliasing the thing in the shell (it is not global that way, and cannot evoke it in vim for example).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You link or copy `ack-grep` to `/usr/local/bin` so that it gets prioritary in the PATH:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ack-grep /usr/local/bin/ack
```

Or, like davey suggested, get rid of `ack` if you don't need it:

```
sudo apt-get remove ack
```

Another solution would involve using `dpkg-divert` to tell `dpkg` that you want all packages to have their `/usr/bin/ack` renamed locally and then link `ack-grep` to `ack` in the path.

Answer (score 20):

In Ubuntu/Debian you can "divert" `ack-grep`:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --divert /usr/bin/ack --rename --add /usr/bin/ack-grep
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the Debian Alternatives system.

```
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ack ack /usr/bin/ack-grep 100 \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/ack.1p.gz ack.1p.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ack-grep.1p.gz
```

The command is tricky to get right, but the solution is superior to dpkg-divert for the following reasons:

1. Does not force or override package installation
2. Enables setting a slave link for the manpage

More info on Debian Alternatives here:
http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives

Installing the alternative enables invoking ack-grep as `ack` and reading the manpage using `man ack`.

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO!

Comment: This is the "right" Debian/Ubuntu way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest thing to do is install ack via cpan.  It will get installed in /usr/local/bin, which has precedence over /usr/bin.  Just run:

```
sudo cpan App::Ack
```

or if you don't have the cpan client:

```
curl -L cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::Ack
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Error message: "Don't be silly, you can't install daniel bosold". But `sudo cpan -i App::Ack` does.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is not secure?

Answer (score 7):

Least obtrusive:

> alias ack=ack-grep

Comment: The question asks for something other than alias, correctly noting that this solution is pretty limited and can't help with shelling out from Vim or bash scripts.

Comment: @IanGreenleaf wow, you're right - embarrassing to see that 4 years later! Oops :/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the kanji translator is not already /usr/bin/ack and that its location is later in your path than /usr/bin, then you can probably do this:

```
sudo ln -sib /usr/bin/ack-grep /usr/bin/ack
```

This will prompt you to confirm the operation if the destination exists and creates a backup if you select yes.

Comment: Unfortunately the kanji ack lives in /usr/bin so if you can live without it:

sudo apt-get remove ack

Answer (score 0):

i'd go with the symlink option as it saves the danger of transferring that alias to another machine if you copy your bash file.

go with this, works fine on my build of ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ack-grep /usr/local/bin/ack
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not so clean because it write in `/bin/` but as long as `/usr/bin/ack` is a binary and not a symlink, was easier for me to fix this way.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/ack ack /usr/bin/ack 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/ack ack /usr/bin/ack-grep 102
```

To choose which one to use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ack
```